# Sub-classes that add new methods

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

I'm writing a class `Tracker` that will expose to the client methods to get the current status of user's training, like distance, pace, calories, etc. Imagine this values as **getters**.

```java
class Tracker{
  float getDistance();
  float getTime();
  float getCalories();
}
```

Now, thinking ahead, I may discover a way to also get the elevation, and then maybe (not at the same time) the number of steps, so my problem is how to better solve this design.

### First thought, classic inheritance

My first thought was to just subclass this interface, so I'll end up with

```java
class ElevationTracker extends BaseTracker{

   float getElevation();

}
```

But then, I may want to add a `StepTracker`, extending the `ElevationTracker` so I have both stats.

```java
class StepTracker extends ElevationTracker{

   float getStepsCount();

}
```

This looks a bit weird to me, because the `StepTracker` now **implicitly** provides the Elevation stat, and it could have been the other way around, the `ElevationTracker`extending `StepTracker`, in this case it's just a matter of which feature I discover first.

Also, I'm not completely sure if this inheritance is consistent with the **specialization** philosophy

### A single class for everything

Another idea, maybe the simplest, is to have just one class `Tracker` and any time I want to add a new feature, change this class by adding a new method to it to retrieve this feature's information; and then the client can update its code to use this new features.
So for example, next month I change the `Tracker` class and it looks like this

```java
class Tracker{
  float getDistance();
  float getTime();
  float getCalories();

  //This is new
  float getElevation();
}
```

I think this solution like if I had thought of this **Elevation** feature before (The first time I created `Tracker` class), I would have added this last method from the beginning.

I do it now just because now the "requirements have changed"

### Making each feature a class

Another thought was to not think every feature as the methods of a class, but as a class on its own, meaning that I would have an interface like `Tracker`

```java
interface Tracker {

  float getValue();

  /** Maybe some other methods */

}
```

and then have a class for each feature

- `DistanceTracker`
- `TimeTracker`
- `CaloriesTracker`
- ...

So then I would just add a new `ElevationTracker`and a `StepTracker`that are independent from each other.

The problem here is that there are some features that depend on others, like for example `PaceTracker` and `CaloriesTracker` may depend on `DistanceTracker`, so they will probably need receive an instance of `DistanceTracker`.

Also, the client code may become a bit messy, having to hold an instance for each feature.
And the most important pitfall I see is that I would usually use all this trackers together, I probable won't use just the `DistanceTracker` or just the `ElevationTracker`, so maybe there's no benefit in having each feature separately

### Conclusion

I would like to know which of this options is the best, or if there's another better option. Maybe I can reconsider one of them with some tweaks or adding a design pattern to improve it.

In my opinion, the **Single class** option provides faster development, considering that, although the others make use of OOP features, they just move the problem of updating a class already written from the Tracker class to another client or intermediate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly pointed out, inheritance does not make a case here because there is not a IS-A relationship between trackers. Composition can be used if one tracker needs other trackers to calculate its value. As per the Single Responsibility principle of SOLID design principles, one class or method should do one particular thing. Applying this principle in this case, it makes sense to create different classes or interfaces for each kind of tracker. It may be good to have interfaces for each kind of tracker and the corresponding implementation classes. So for example, interfaces such as IDistanceTracker, IElevationTracker, IStepTracker and so on can be created along with their implementations such as DistanceTrackerImpl, ElevationTrackerImpl and so on.

By coding against interfaces, we are keeping the code flexible to supply a different implementation of the same tracker in the future. For example in the client code we can use interfaces and in the service code, we can potentially use multiple implementations of the same interface and do things like use one kind of implementation for specific set of clients and use another for the rest. The client code doesn't have to change in this case. And sometimes, let's say we want to upgrade certain clients to use a newer version of the implementation - hypothetically speaking - a wearable device 1.0 hardware is capable of tracking only steps and let's say we display the consumed calories based on the steps then the Calorie Tracker can calculate the calories based on the steps. And let's say in the newer wearable hardware 2.0, the hardware is capable of tracking elevation as well, in that the Calorie Tracker for the newer hardware will need to be modified to use the elevation data to calculate calories. But the old devices should still use previous calorie tracker which uses only steps and not the elevation. This results in the need to have multiple implementations of the same tracker and hence it is better to code against the interface by having a single interface ICalorieTracker and multiple implementations of the same.

Thus, IMHO, having individual interfaces and implementations for each tracker without any inheritance relationship might be a good idea. If there is a tracker that satisfies the IS-A relationship then one tracker interface can extend the other. For example, IAdvancedCalorieTracker extends ICalorieTracker. Here the subtype satisfies the IS-A relationship, so it would be okay to use inheritance.

Comment: Great answer, I see your point. As I said having individual interfaces for each tracker may cause the client to handle many interfaces on its own, so building on top of your idea, would you recommend to implement an _Abstract Factory_ to group trackers together for a given set of clients ?

Another thing, at the moment for each feature there is just one method, the **get[Feature]()** method, so every interface will have just one method, idk if this will change later but do you think this should be considered ? I mean it's all this system design still worth it for just that method ?

Comment: AF is intended for creating factories of variations of same kind of objects. Here, each tracker is a different. Hence AF pattern may not fit here. Assuming it is a client server design and layered architecture where client calls the server to get the data from all trackers, a wrapper data transfer object that contains data from all trackers & gets sent to the client can be used so that on the client side, it gets data from just one object. Thus client calls the server endpoint, controller layer calls different tracker service classes to aggregate the data using interfaces ex - IDistanceTracker

Comment: Regarding whether to extend the design now or not depends on the velocity of the project. It is always a trade off between having a detailed well thought out design vs delivering it faster. This doesn't look like it involves more effort to design these classes and could be definitely considered. In any case, domain model of the system should be designed carefully because that doesn't change so frequently and its very hard to change later on. Regarding if it is worth it, based on my experience, having a good modular design always pays off when things change later.